# Center group of images not working ( classes )

Tags: html, css, wordpress

No matter what I have tried - I can not seem to get a group of images to center on my page. Anyone have any thoughts? This is wracking my brain.

breakwatersurf.com is where the uncentered images are. You will see the shop mens and shop womens don't line up with the bottom divider lines.

Stack overflow doesn't like my code and wont allow me to use code tags so please inspect the elements on my webpage for html / css

I Have tried so many variations of css without any luck. I know the answer is simple but I can't seem to find out why my won't center anywhere.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Paste the relevant code into your question. Highlight it. Click the `{}` button. You cant expect people to trawl through your source code

Comment: Just add `text-align: center` to that `p` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give to the shop womens image a `float: right` style in your **CSS**. I did this with the element inspector and it works:

```
<img class="groupcenter" src="http://breakwatersurfcompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/righthalf.png" alt="righthalf" width="565" height="500" style="float:right">
```

[image]

And learn how to use the site. People here don't like to help if you don't follow the site rules.

Comment: Why does it have to be such a simple answer - I feel like I tried that more than once.. Oh well, some times you just need different eyes on it I guess. Thanks.